# ¿Como agregar archivo a programa c++, con clases?

Tags: c++, archivo, clase

Como conectar un archivo de texto (no binario), que almacene datos ingresados por el usuario en c++, en este sencillo ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class persona{
private:
 char nombre[40], apellido[40], cedula[40];
public:
 void registrar()
  {
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre"<<endl;
    cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"Ingrese el apellido"<<endl;
    cin>>apellido;
    cout<<"Ingrese la cedula"<<endl;
    cin>>cedula;
  }
void mostrar()
 {
    cout<<"Los datos registrados son los siguientes: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
    getch();
    cout<<"Apellido: "<<apellido<<endl;
    getch();
    cout<<"Cedula: "<<cedula<<endl;
    getch();
 }
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 persona per1;
 per1.registrar();
 per1.mostrar();
 return 0;
}
```

Sus respuesta seria de gran ayuda!! :D

Comment: La respuesta depende del tipo de archivo

Comment: El tipo de archivo es de texto, me refiero a que la informacion ingresada en el programa pueda ser visualizada en un archivo de texto, que almacene los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando C++ lo mas natural puede ser usar la biblioteca fstream para el manejo de los ficheros y sustituir los arreglos de caracteres por string ha no ser que sea obligatorio definir un tamaño fijo de caracteres.

En lo personal no recomiendo combinar la lógica del programa con los "Objetos Clave" en este caso la clase Persona solo debería manejar los datos de la persona en turno y no del registro ni el llenado esto ultimo debería realizarse en otra sección del programa.

Una posible implementacion de la clase Persona seria asi.

```
class Persona
{
private:
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    string cedula;

public:
    Persona(const string& nombre, const string& apellido, const string& cedula)
    {
        this->nombre=nombre;
        this->apellido=apellido;
        this->cedula=cedula;
    }
    //Implementacion
    string getNombre()
    {
        return this->nombre;
    }
    string getApellido()
    {
        return this->apellido;
    }
    string getCedula()
    {
        return this->cedula;
    }
};
```

Después te podrías crear una clase Agenda, no se si en tu caso sea una pero es una idea se podría manejar los datos de las personas.
Bueno en mi caso me cree una clase llamada Agenda donde administrar los registros de las personas y fungirá como una especie de base de datos, en el se podrán agregar nuevos registros o consultar los ya existentes.

```
 class Agenda
{
private:
    fstream file;
    vector<string> split(const string& source,char token);
    bool fileExists(const string& ruta);

public:
    Agenda(const string& ruta);
    void agregar(Persona& persona);
    void agregarTodas(const vector<Persona>& personas);
    vector<Persona> leerTodo();
    ~Agenda();//Destructor de la clase
};

Agenda::Agenda(const string& ruta)
{
    if(fileExists(ruta))
    {
        file.open(ruta.c_str(),fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    }
    else
    {
        file.open(ruta.c_str(),fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
    }
}

vector<string> Agenda::split(const string& source,char token)
{
    std::string sentence="";
    vector<string> result;

    for(char c :source)
    {
        if(c==token)
        {
            result.push_back(sentence);
            sentence="";
            continue;
        }
        sentence.push_back(c);
    }
    return result;
}


bool Agenda::fileExists(const string& ruta)
{
    fstream infile(ruta.c_str());
    return infile.good();
}

void Agenda::agregar(Persona& persona)
{
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        file<<persona.getNombre()<<","<<persona.getApellido()<<","<<persona.getCedula()<<","<<endl;
    }
}

void Agenda::agregarTodas(const vector<Persona>& personas)
{
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        for(Persona p: personas)
        {
            file<<p.getNombre()<<","<<p.getApellido()<<","<<p.getCedula()<<","<<endl;
        }
    }
}

vector<Persona> Agenda::leerTodo()
{
    vector<Persona> personas;
    if(file.good())
    {
        file.seekg(0,file.beg);//Nos ponemos al inicio del fichero
        string linea;
        while(getline(file,linea))
        {
            vector<string> tokens=split(linea,',');
            string nombre=tokens[0];
            string apellido=tokens[1];
            string cedula=tokens[2];

            Persona p(nombre,apellido,cedula);
            personas.push_back(p);

        }
    }
    return personas;
}

Agenda::~Agenda()
{
    file.close();
}
```

Una puesta en marcha de las dos clases trabajando en conjunto seria esta:

```
int main()
{
    //Creamos el objeto Agenda si el archivo no existe se crea, si existe se anade datos a la agenda
    Agenda agenda("C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\agenda.txt");

    //Agregamos 1 persona
    Persona p=Persona("luis","arturo","0435845");
    agenda.agregar(p);

    vector<Persona> personas;
    personas.push_back(Persona("Mari","Perez","34353543"));
    personas.push_back(Persona("Jose","Arturo","9343533"));
    agenda.agregarTodas(personas);

    vector<Persona> datosLeidos=agenda.leerTodo();

    for(Persona p:datosLeidos)
    {
        cout<<p.getNombre()<<" "<<p.getApellido()<<" "<<p.getCedula()<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"\nPrograma terminado"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

En ella podemos ver que la clase Agenda se encarga de administrar la creación y lectura de nuestro fichero, si el fichero no existe lo crea y si ya existe solo agrega registros al final, al mismo tiempo que accede a los datos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, gracias por tomarte el tiempo; algunas cosas las entiendo y otras no (son nuevas para mi), igual me ayuda un poco para el proyecto que realizo de la universidad.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo usar **JSON** para hacer esto, aca una libreria [Json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

Comment: Gracias por tu recomendacion, soy novato y no se implementarlo, un ejemplo usando este mismo codigo que di no vendria mal. =D

Comment: Solo es para Guardar o También Leerlos?

Comment: Ambas funciones, cade recalcar  que es un simple .txt, sin orden espefico, que se almacene de forma secuencial.

Answer (score 0):

Para leer un archivo puedes usar la interfaz heredada de C o los objetos propios de c++.

En el caso de elegir la interfaz de C, todo se basa en el handler FILE:

```
FILE* fich = fopen("fichero.txt","r");
if(!fich) return;

while(feof(fich))
{
  // Lectura de los registros
}
fclose(fich);
```

En el caso de optar por los objetos de c++ puedes usar la librería iostream:

```
std::ifstream fich("fichero.txt");
while(fich.good())
{
  // Lectura de los registros
}
fich.close();
```

Si no te especifico una forma concreta de leer los datos es porque no has indicado la forma en que están almacenados.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, lo siento por no ser tan especifico, el archivo es de texto (.txt) secuncial comun, que se pueda ver lo que ingreso el usuario abriendo el .txt , lo que busco al formular esta pregunta es realizar un programa que, la informacion que ingrese se guarde y al cerrar, iniciando el programa esten esos mismos datos; claro usando este mismo ejemplo que di para guiarme y que se me haga sencillo de entender, disculpa si en algunas partes mi conocimiento no es muy amplio, soy un novato aun.